OnDriver error Bad Request 400 al intentar subir un archivo
Estoy desarrollando un programa en VB NET para conectar con OnDriver y subir archivos al mismo.
Ya cree la aplicación en Microsoft Entra y le otorgue los permisos y mi programa obtiene el token necesario sin problemas pero al querer obtener cualquier otro dato me da Bad Request 400.
Adjunto la función para obtener el token y para ver los permisos de mi aplicación.
Public Async Function VerifyPermissionsAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)
     Dim ok As Boolean = False
     Using httpClient As New HttpClient()
         Dim accessToken As String = Await GetAccessToken()
         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken)

         Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/permissions")
         If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
             Dim responseContent As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
             Dim permissions As JArray = JArray.Parse(responseContent)
             MsgBox("Permisos concedidos: " & permissions.ToString())
             ok = True
         Else
             MsgBox("Error al verificar los permisos: " & response.ReasonPhrase)
         End If
     End Using
     Return ok
 End Function
 Private Async Function GetAccessToken() As Task(Of String)
     Dim Token As String
     Try
         Dim confidentialClient As IConfidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(mID_Cliente_Aplicacion).WithClientSecret(mClienteClaveSecreta).WithAuthority(New Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mID_Directorio_Tenant}")).Build()
         Dim scopes As String() = {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"}
         Dim authResult As Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult = Await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync()
         Token = authResult.AccessToken
     Catch ex As Exception
         Token = ""
         MsgBox($"Error obteniendo el token de acceso: {ex.Message}", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
     End Try
     Return Token
 End Function

